# Change navbar font color on different carousels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I really do not know how to handle this problem so pleaaase help me!

I have a full-page slider (on home page) in this project. Inside the slider I have 5 items with different pictures.

I would like to change the color of the navbar's text on the first slide/carousel item and the rest can look the same. First should be grey and on the last 4 slides the navbar's text should be white.

I also would like to change the logo inside the navbar (on the first slide it should be grey and on the last 4 slides it should be white also. I have 2 pngs to do this work.)

Here are 2 pictures to demonstrate what I would like to do:
[slider1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2M5o.png)
[slider2 (rest of sliders)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0bR9.png)

HTML:

```
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbarmargin container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><img src="muszerfal_elements/img/menu2.png" style="max-width: 38px; padding-right: 4px; margin-top: 6px;"/>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="index.html">
                <img class="logo" src="img/final_2.png">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" >
            <ul class="navbartext nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="works.html">Works</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="personal.html">Personal</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- Full Page Image Background Carousel Header -->
<header id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/slider_1.jpg');" alt="Slide 1"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption caption1">
                <h2>Fashion</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/slider_3.jpg');" alt="Slide 2"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption caption2">
                <h2>Fashion</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/slider_4.jpg');" alt="Slide 3"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption caption3">
                <h2>Beauty</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/slider_5.jpg');" alt="Slide 3"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption caption4">
                <h2>Fine Art</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</header>
```

Can you help me how to start with this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are trying to do is similar to fullPage.js, it allows for a full page slider and I believe using some basic CSS you could implement the desired changing colour feature. http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage

Comment: Exactly. By using the [callbacks](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks) or [fullPage.js state classes](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#state-classes-added-by-fullpagejs).

Check a callbacks demo [here](http://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/XbPNQv) and a video tutorial regarding the state classes [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M).

Answer (score 0):

.carousel-inner>.item:first-child h2 {color: black;}

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is the slider you're using: https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-full-slider

Changing the color of the text on the first slide is not a problem (see example below). However, I don't think this slider has a callback function that returns what slide it is on. This would be required to change the font color of the nav bar depending on which slide you are on. So I think you'll have to look for another full-page slider that would allow you to do this.

```css
/*
 * Start Bootstrap - Full Slider (http://startbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2013-2016 Start Bootstrap
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap/blob/gh-pages/LICENSE)
 */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel,
.item,
.active {
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Background images are set within the HTML using inline CSS, not here */

.fill {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}

footer {
  margin: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Full Slider - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbarmargin container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><img src="http://placehold.it/25x25" style="max-width: 38px; padding-right: 4px; margin-top: 6px;"/>
            </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="index.html">
          <img class="logo" src="http://placehold.it/25x25">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="navbartext nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <a href="works.html">Works</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="personal.html">Personal</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <!-- Full Page Image Background Carousel Header -->
  <header id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080/ffffff');" alt="Slide 1"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption caption1" style="color: grey;">
          <h2>Fashion (this text is grey)</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080');" alt="Slide 2"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption caption2">
          <h2>Fashion (this text is white)</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080');" alt="Slide 3"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption caption3">
          <h2>Beauty</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080');" alt="Slide 3"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption caption4">
          <h2>Fine Art</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </header>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Script to Activate the Carousel -->
  <script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 5000 //changes the speed
    })
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```